# Occur '405 Method not allowed' and 'request was aborded' Error When i use HTTP type to get RabbitMQ Message

Tags: request, httprequest, webclient, rabbitmq

I have these code in .NET VB.NET:

```
Dim serverIP As String = "172.16.1.24"

    Dim localIP As String = "172.16.1.27-RMSDESKTOP"

    Dim port As Integer = 55672

    Dim apiAddr As String = "/api/queues/%2f/" & localIP & "/get"
  
    Dim requestAddr As String = "http://" & serverIP & ":" & port & apiAddr

    Debug.WriteLine(requestAddr)

    wb = New System.Net.WebClient

    While isConnect = True

    Dim postBody As String = My.Settings.body1    '' it is correct json parameters

wb.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    wb.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("guest", "guest")

    Dim result As String = wb.UploadString(requestAddr, "POST", postBody)

    If result IsNot Nothing AndAlso result.Length > 0 Then

    Debug.WriteLine(Now.ToString & ":" & "RESPONSE:  " & result)
  
    End If
```

Occur `'405 Method not allowed' and 'request was aborted'` Error When i use HTTP type to get RabbitMQ Message.

Sometimes occurs `'405 Method not allowed'`, Sometimes occurs

```
'request was aborted' error.
```

Our username,password,port,queue name and server ip are all correct. and i use 'PUT' Method to try but also occurs ERROR-->: the underlying connection was closed, unable to read data from the transport connection.

REFERENCE : 
http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_0_1/priv/www/api/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Dim port As Integer = 15672
```

instead of

```
Dim port As Integer = 55672
```

The port changed in RabbitMQ 3.0 and up -
see the [RabbitMQ Blog](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/11/19/breaking-things-with-rabbitmq-3-0/)